# call callback with reference to field

Tags: rust

Consider such code:

```
trait OnUpdate {
    fn on_update(&mut self, x: &i32);
}

struct Foo {
    field: i32,
    cbs: Vec<Box<OnUpdate>>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn subscribe(&mut self, cb: Box<OnUpdate>) {
        self.cbs.push(cb);
    }
    fn set_x(&mut self, v: i32) {
        self.field = v;

        //variant 1
        //self.call_callbacks(|v| v.on_update(&self.field));

        //variant 2
        let f_ref = &self.field;
        for item in &mut self.cbs {
            item.on_update(f_ref);
        }
    }
    fn call_callbacks<CB: FnMut(&mut Box<OnUpdate>)>(&mut self, mut cb: CB) {
        for item in &mut self.cbs {
            cb(item);
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment variant 2 and uncomment variant 1,
it doesn't compiles, because of I need `&Foo` and `&mut Foo` at the same time.

But I really need function in this place, because of I need the same
code to call callbacks in several places.

So do I need macros here to call callbacks, or may be another solution?

Side notes: in real code I use big structure instead of `i32`,
so I can not copy it. Also I have several methods in `OnUpdate`,
so I need `FnMut` in `call_callbacks`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important rule of Rust's borrow checker is, *mutable access is exclusive access.*

In variant 2, this rule is upheld because the reference to `self.field` and to `mut self.cbs` never really overlap. The `for` loop implicitly invokes `into_iter` on `&mut Vec`, which returns a `std::slice::IterMut` object that references the *vector*, but not the rest of `Foo`. In other words, the `for` loop does not really contain a mutable borrow of `self`.

In variant 1, there is a `call_callbacks` which does retain a mutable borrow of self, which means it cannot receive (directly on indirectly) *another* borrow of self. In other words, at the same time:

1. It accepts a mutable reference to `self`, which allows it to modify all its fields, including `self.field`.
2. It accepts a closure that *also* refers to `self`, because it uses the expression `self.field`.

Letting this compile would allow `call_callbacks` to mutate `self.field` without the closure being aware of it. In case of an integer it might not sound like a big deal, but for other data this would lead to bugs that Rust's borrow checker is explicitly designed to prevent. For example, Rust relies on these properties to prevent unsafe iteration over mutating containers or data races in multi-threaded programs.

In your case it is straightforward to avoid the above situation. `set_x` is in control both of the contents of the closure and of the mutation to `self.field`. It could be restated to pass a temporary variable to the closure, and then update `self.field`, like this:

```
impl Foo {
    fn subscribe(&mut self, cb: Box<OnUpdate>) {
        self.cbs.push(cb);
    }
    fn set_x(&mut self, v: i32) {
        self.call_callbacks(|cb| cb.on_update(&v));
        self.field = v;
    }

    fn call_callbacks<OP>(&mut self, mut operation: OP)
        where OP: FnMut(&mut OnUpdate)
    {
        for cb in self.cbs.iter_mut() {
            operation(&mut **cb);
        }
    }
}
```

Rust has no problem with this code, and effect is the same.

As an exercise, it is possible to write a version of `call_callbacks` that works like variant 2. In that case, it needs to accept an iterator into the cbs `Vec`, much like the `for` loop does, and it must not accept `&self` at all:

```
fn set_x(&mut self, v: i32) {
    self.field = v;
    let fref = &self.field;
    Foo::call_callbacks(&mut self.cbs.iter_mut(),
                        |cb| cb.on_update(fref));
}

fn call_callbacks<OP>(it: &mut Iterator<Item=&mut Box<OnUpdate>>,
                      mut operation: OP)
    where OP: FnMut(&mut OnUpdate)
{
    for cb in it {
        operation(&mut **cb);
    }
}
```